# Creating an instance of class?

Tags: java, object, treemap

I keep receiving the error indicated below. I assume I'm not declaring it properly:

```
public class SparseMatrix {

// instance variables 
private final TreeMap<Integer,TreeMap<Integer,Double>> matrix;
private final int rows;
private final int cols;

public SparseMatrix(int r, int c) {
              // this gives me an error
    this.rows = new SparseMatrix(r);
    this.cols = new SparseMatrix(c);

} // end of constructor
}
```

Comment: What's the error bro?  Also, rows and cols are int.  Why are you making them SparseMatrix?

Comment: rows is int type and your trying to assign instance of SparseMatrix.

Comment: Potentially I see a lot of errors. Looks like the answers have all of them covered though.

Comment: I could say 90% of the cases, the error message is very explicit about what's wrong in the code and give you a hint about how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a constructor for `SparseMatrix` that takes a single int argument. Also, `this.rows` and `this.cols` are `int` values, not `SparseMatrix` fields. Also, you need to initialize the `final` field `matrix` in the constructor. You probably want this:

```
public class SparseMatrix {

    // instance variables 
    private final TreeMap<Integer,TreeMap<Integer,Double>> matrix;
    private final int rows;
    private final int cols;

    public SparseMatrix(int r, int c) {
        this.rows = r;
        this.cols = c;
        this.matrix = new TreeMap<>();
    } // end of constructor

}
```

Comment: Also you need to initialize `matrix` in constructor.

Comment: In addition you may want to initialise `matrix` in the constructor.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - Got it.

Answer (score 0):

matrix is final so needs to be declared either in its declaration or in the constructor. Remove the final and you should compile ok although you'll need to initialise matrix at some point if you want to use it.

Also rows and cols are meant to be ints but you are assigning SparseMatric objects

I suspect you want something like

```
private TreeMap<Integer,TreeMap<Integer,Double>> matrix;
private final int rows;
private final int cols;

public SparseMatrix(int r, int c) {
  this.rows = r;
  this.cols = c;
}
```

and then you'll use rows and cols in the matrix somehow. With more info we can help more ;)

Comment: Marking fields as `final` means their value cannot be modified after creating the instance of the class.

Comment: The rows and cols need to be final

Answer (score 0):

`this.rows` and `this.col` are of **type** `int`, yet you are attempting to instantiate them as `SparseMatrix`.  It's also problematic that you unconditionally instantiate a `SparseMatrix` within a `SparseMatrix`.  Think about when that cycle terminates...